# Joining LINQ results with IEnumerable

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-4, asp.net-web-api

I have an API written in .NET 4.5 using Entity Framework. Here is what one of the methods looks like:

```
private myEntities db = new myEntities();

// GET api/User
public IEnumerable<User> GetUsers()
{
    return from u in db.Users
           select u;
}
```

Pretty simple. This table can join with a Roles table, so a User can have many Roles. The foreign key UserId is in the Roles table. Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
private myEntities db = new myEntities();

// GET api/User
public IEnumerable<User> GetUsers()
{
    return from u in db.Users
           join r in db.Roles on u.UserId equals r.UserId
           select new User
           {
               UserId = u.UserId,
               Roles = u.Roles
           };
}
```

This throws an error: **The entity or complex type 'ppadModel.User' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query**

How do I write a query that returns the User and all the Roles associated with that user?

Comment: You should use EF's built-in support for relations and create a navigation property.  You then won't need to do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the .Include extension method.

Like this:

```
return from u in db.Users.Include("Roles")
select u;
```

You can also use lamba expression to avoid strings:

```
return from u in db.Users.Include(x => x.Roles)
select u;
```

This tells the Entity Framework to load all users and additional all associated roles for the users.

Comment: Thanks. I actually tried that previously but had the property for Roles in the User model set to "internal get", ruining my results: public virtual ICollection<Role> Roles { internal get; set; }